# SSIS project fail to build - CPackage::LoadFromXML fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, sql-server-data-tools

I have been trying to solve a SSIS project related problem for a week now.
The SSIS solution/project has been working fine for two years but is not working at all for a second user after adding him two weeks ago.

The user can open the solution and execute packages after connecting to the source code via VSO/TFS or by using a local copy.
But after making changes to the project the other user got the error message (1) below when trying to build the project or executing a package.
Trying to import the project from the server results in another error message (2).

Most posts I have find refer to versions of SQL/visual studio (project created on a version that differs to the one currently in use) it is not appicable to my case

Any help or feedback highly appriciated.

My conditions are:
SQL Server 2014 (including SSIS) on win server 2012 r2
Dev machine with win 10 and SQL Server Data Tools 2013 (latest version)
Visual Studio Online for source code/versioning (GIT)
SSIS project deployment model
ProtectionLevel = EncryptSensitiveWithPassword

What I have tried so far:
Tried all cominations of user and dev machine
Tried different versions of Data tools
Tried to find differences in project/solution files as well as in packages to identify user related code etc.
Tried the SSI project with and without source control
Tried to change the Run64BitRunTime property

(1)

Error 1 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.LoadPackage(String FileName, Boolean loadNeutral, IDTSEvents100 pEvents) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events, Boolean loadNeutral) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events, Boolean loadNeutral) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events) at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.ProjectBuildItemInfo.Update(DateTime lastWriteTime, PackageItem packageItem, Project project, String projectDirectory) at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.ProjectBuildItemInfo..ctor(String name, DateTime lastWriteTime, PackageItem packageItem, Project project, String projectDirectory) at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.ProjectBuildValidator.RefreshCache(PackageItem item) at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.ProjectBuildValidator.CheckBuildItem(PackageItem item) at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.ProjectBuildValidator.CheckConsistency(String& errors, String buildLogFullName) at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughObj(IOutputWindow outputWindow) at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow outputWindow)

(2)

The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

Comment: Do you have any custom SSIS components within the package?

Comment: No custom SSIS components
The only thing I have added from the "out of the box" SSIS is an excel/access driver to read excel files

Comment: Does the other user have the access driver installed?  If so, is it the same version and bitness as what you have installed?

Comment: yes
I am starting to think that the problem is source control related
The (other) user download the SSIS project and it works fine
The user makes a "dummy" change and it does not work any more
A copy of the changed code is executed as my user and it works

Comment: This has finally been solved.
I had an Microsoft odata driver installed and a package connection manager that used that driver in one of the packages.
Removing that connectoion manager solved the problem.

I find it really strange though that you are able to build the project "untouched" and that this connection is somehow validated only after changes are made to the project or if you import the project from the server (integration services catalog).
Also unfortunate that SSIS was unable to produce a "better" error message.

Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party I'm afraid, but I managed to resolve the 2nd error (in my case anyway) by using importing using the .ispac file rather than connecting to the catalogue in the database.